# Error using curl_init() in php environment on BlueMix

Tags: php, api, curl, ibm-cloud

I use the PHP runtime on Bluemix. In my solution, I need to invoke the external API available on the Internet on port 3000.

I used curl to manage the API invocation using the following code:

```
$endPoint="http://".$this->server.":".$this->port.$endPoint;
$session = curl_init($endPoint);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($session);
```

In the Bluemix log I found the following error:

```
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function
curl_init() in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/include/service.php on line 50\n',
referer: http://m2msite.mybluemix.net/login.php
```

It does not seem to be a defined curl library inside my runtime.
I do not found any documentation on how to define the curl library in a Bluemix runtime.

Can anyone help me to configure my runtime in a correct way?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` if you have access to console

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.

under the project root I create a directory **.bp-config**
Inside the directory I create a file **option.json** with the following content:

```
{
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["mysqli","curl"]
}
```

**mysqli** for mysql library and **curl** for the curl library.

So now I am able to use curl library inside my project

Has anyone the link for a complete documentation around this configuration steps ?

Ciao

Answer (score 1):

the complete documentation for your this kind of configuration related to a PHP buildpack could be found here

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html